# Determine color based on similarity of hexadecimal string / binary number

Tags: c#, binary, hex

This looks like a strange question.

I've encountered it in a youtube video where objects had a string attribute.
The graphical representation of the objects was coloured based on the similarity of the string.

The string was defined as a hexadecimal representation of a binary number. For example "915BB352" as a representation of "10010001010110111011001101010010".

What approach can I use in C# to get this behaviour?

So "10010001010110111011001101010010" and "10010001010110111011001101010000" should have a similar color.
"10010001010110111011001101010010" and "01100100110001101010100001011111" should be quite different.

Comment: How these two colors are same

Comment: This makes no sense imo. What video are you referring to?? Color distance/similarity is not a well-defined thing..

Comment: I refer to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3tRFayqVtk. Each "creature" has a genome that is represented by strings. The color of the creatures is defined by those strings and over time the colors of all creatures align. I know it's a different language than C#, but I want to understand the approach behind it.

Comment: @Shintaro could you mark my answer please. I need those points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using hex or binrary, try converting hex color to HSL then you can use HSL to determine the difference, simply by measuring the difference in `Hue`, then compare the `Lightness` and Finally the `Saturation`

`Red: hsla(360, 100%, 50%, 1)`
`Blue: hsla(250, 100%, 50%, 1)`

The difference would be:

`(360 - 250), (100% - 100%), ( 50% - %50%), (1-1)`

Difference Equals:
`= 10, 0, 0, 0`

Which is quite different

#### Definition

HSL (for hue, saturation, lightness) and HSV (for hue, saturation, value; also known as HSB, for hue, saturation, brightness) are alternative representations of the RGB color model, designed in the 1970s by computer graphics researchers to more closely align with the way human vision perceives color-making attributes.

[image]

```cs
public static HSLColor FromRGB(Byte R, Byte G, Byte B)
    {
        float _R = (R / 255f);
        float _G = (G / 255f);
        float _B = (B / 255f);

        float _Min = Math.Min(Math.Min(_R, _G), _B);
        float _Max = Math.Max(Math.Max(_R, _G), _B);
        float _Delta = _Max - _Min;

        float H = 0;
        float S = 0;
        float L = (float)((_Max + _Min) / 2.0f);

        if (_Delta != 0)
        {
            if (L < 0.5f)
            {
                S = (float)(_Delta / (_Max + _Min));
            }
            else
            {
                S = (float)(_Delta / (2.0f - _Max - _Min));
            }


            if (_R == _Max)
            {
                H = (_G - _B) / _Delta;
            }
            else if (_G == _Max)
            {
                H = 2f + (_B - _R) / _Delta;
            }
            else if (_B == _Max)
            {
                H = 4f + (_R - _G) / _Delta;
            }
        }

        return new HSLColor(H, S, L);
    }
```

You can play with [HSL Here](https://hslpicker.com/)